# How to use the default SiteSqlServer database connection from the web.config - DotNetNuke

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to use the default SiteSqlServer connection for my custom DotNetNuke module. However, when I added a dataset, the wizard gave me the option to create a new connection. I can't find anywhere the existing connection string from the web.config. 
Is there a way to select it or add it manually on my dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the DNN Module Development Wiki entry, it'll get you up to speed on how things are done in DNN.

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/Page/Module-Development

The standard approach is to use the DAL (data access layer) which provides easy access to the connectionstring available in DNN.